# How to create directory and subdirectory if it does not exist in sharepoint Document Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, create-directory

I have a user input as `D:\Test1\Test2\Test3\Test4\a\b\c\d\file.jpg` as per the user input i need to check if folder and sub folder exist in a Document Library.

i.e

DocLib>>Test1>>Test2....d  i want to replicate the folder structure in Document Library, if it exist than directly read and save the file else create directory and than subdirectory and upto the level wherin file should be saved.

Can anyone help me to understand how can i go with this? I tried with creating files in local system on hard drive

```
static void CopyFolder(string sourceFolder, string destFolder)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(sourceFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
                string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
                File.Copy(file, dest);
            }

            //check folder in the source destination
            string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder);
            foreach (string folder in folders)
            {
                string name = Path.GetFileName(folder);
                string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dest);
                CopyFolder(folder, dest);
            }
        }
```

No idea how to check if directory exist and than check for subdirectory in sharepoint. i.e add a file by retaining the folder structure specified. Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you will need to createthe structure of the tree path one by one: here is a short code how it can be done on the root site with UserDocument folder as a root folder:

```
            // This will contain all information about the path
            DirectoryInfo infoDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures2\WallPaperHD - 078.jpg");

            // Root folder passed => Default in SharePoint
            if (infoDir.Parent != null)
            {
                // All folders are stored here
                List<string> folders = new List<string>();

                // Set current folder to parent
                DirectoryInfo currentDir = infoDir.Parent;
                do
                {
                    // Add its name to array
                    folders.Add(currentDir.Name);

                    // Set parent of current as current if available
                    if (currentDir.Parent != null)
                        currentDir = currentDir.Parent;
                }
                while (currentDir.Parent != null);

                // Add SP structure)
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://testsite.dev"))
                {
                    SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
                    // Get doc library
                    SPList documentLibrary = web.GetList("/UserDocuments");
                    // If library root exists
                    if (documentLibrary != null)
                    {
                        string folderUrl = "/UserDocuments/";

                        for (int i = folders.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            string folder = folders[i];
                            SPFolder newFolder = site.RootWeb.GetFolder(folderUrl + folder);
                            if (!newFolder.Exists)
                            {
                                site.RootWeb.Folders.Add(folderUrl + folder);
                                // Save changes
                                site.RootWeb.Update();

                                folderUrl += folder + "/";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This will create the same structure of folders on the SharePoint side as it was specified in the path passed by user.

After this all you need is to save file in the specified folder.

Hope it helps,

Andrew